# JavaFX ComboBox containing Bytes

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I used to use a `JComboBox` to select a byte in Swing like this.

```
public synchronized void callPresetButtonActionPerformed(
                java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            byte _preset = (byte)getPresetcomboBox.getSelectedItem();

                try {
                    something=presetNo[_preset-1];

                byte[] command = {(byte) startTx, address, byteOne, goPreset, 0x00, something, endTx, 0x0F};                
                TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                        twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());

            sw.out.write(command);

            } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
Byte[] preset = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Now I am moving to JavaFX and I am trying to do the same thing.

```
@FXML
public void setPresetButton (ActionEvent event) {
    byte _preset = (Byte)setPresetComboBox.getSelectedItem();
    try {
        something=presetNo[_preset-1];

        byte[] command = {(byte) startTx, address, byteOne, setPreset, 0x00, something, endTx, 0x0F};               
        TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());

    sw.out.write(command);

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
Byte[] preset = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

And I recieve an error: `The method getSelectedItem() is undefined for the type ComboBox<Byte>`.

I think I understand the meaning of the error but how do I work around it in JavaFX?

Comment: The error message tells you the solution: there is no `getSelectedItem()` method for a `ComboBox`. You can get the selected item through its selection model: `setPresetComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();` or by getting the value: `setPresetComboBox.getValue()`.

Comment: Ok it turns out i didn't understand the error at all. post as an answer and i will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message tells, the method `getSelectedItem()` does not exist for JavaFX `ComboBox`.

You can either use the [getSelectedItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SelectionModel.html#getSelectedItem--) of the [selection model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html#getSelectionModel--) of the `ComboBox` as

```
setPresetComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
```

or the [value property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBoxBase.html#getValue--) of the `ComboBox` directly as

```
setPresetComboBox.getValue();
```

The difference between these two properties is documented in the [javadoc of ComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html):

> The ComboBox exposes the ComboBoxBase.valueProperty() from
>   ComboBoxBase, but there are some important points of the value
>   property that need to be understood in relation to ComboBox. These
>   include:
>
> - The value property is not constrained to items contained within the items list - it can be anything as long as it is a valid value of
>     type T.
> - If the value property is set to a non-null object, and subsequently the items list is cleared, the value property is not
>     nulled out.
> - Clearing the selection in the selection model does not null the value property - it remains the same as before.
> - It is valid for the selection model to have a selection set to a given index even if there is no items in the list (or less items in
>     the list than the given index). Once the items list is further
>     populated, such that the list contains enough items to have an item in
>     the given index, both the selection model
>     SelectionModel.selectedItemProperty() and value property will be
>     updated to have this value. This is inconsistent with other controls
>     that use a selection model, but done intentionally for ComboBox.